# Is America more egalitarian than other countries?

Tags: united-states, social-class, egalitarianism

There is a widely held perception that USA is a land of equal opportunities. A country wherein citizens are not bound by the constraints of a rigid or semi-rigid class system. This is the essence of the [American Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Dream) and arguably what the Founding Fathers had in mind when they penned in the Declaration of Independence:

> We hold these truths to be self-evident, that all men are created
> equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable
> Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of
> Happiness.

It is debatable whether the USA historically matched these ideals with slavery being a standout counteraxmple. However, my interest is USA in the recent past.

Since defining class is difficult, I will use wealth as a proxy. Is it the case that in the USA, a greater percentage of those born poor (by some metric) achieve wealth during their lifetime (by some metric) than in other countries? If not, which country is the most egalitarian in this sense?

Comment: You want to search on terms like (Intergenerational) "Social Mobility" which I believe is the accepted term for this type of concern.  https://www.oecd.org/social/labour/49849281.pdf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Social_Mobility_Index

Comment: The question is a bit vague. More than most or more than all? Denmark is #1, so the latter is clearly false, but USA is #27, so better than top 20%.

Comment: There is also an [Egalitarian Index](https://www.theglobaleconomy.com/rankings/egalitarian_democracy_index/) which is a bit different than say, a "Social Mobility" index.

Comment: regarding definition of class in the US, if you're interpreting that in an associative sense, some pretty convincing observations out there that education - rather than wealth or income - is the larger determining factor. E.g. when taking out other factors like race and age, low income high educated groups with high income high educated, contrast vs high income low educated. For those in the US who are also born in the US, education is in turn partially dependent on where one grows up, due to the way the primary and secondary education available to most people is funded thru property taxes

Comment: if talking about distribution (vs intergenerational mobility), and you want to boil it down to one numerical figure, Gini coefficient is a popular measure - https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/gini-coefficient-by-country

Comment: Finally you could take a sort of Rawlsian view (imagine you're to be reincarnated as a completely random person in the US of unknown parents - famous thought experiment says it would be logical in that scenario to desire a social structure which maximize the well-being of the bottom stratum), and thus one could simply compare countries using the well-being of the bottom 10% or bottom 20% or something like that, as the key measure.

Comment: Some resources (don't contain an answer but may be a starting point for others)  [Corellation of wealth and parental wealth](https://spinup-000d1a-wp-offload-media.s3.amazonaws.com/faculty/wp-content/uploads/sites/73/2019/10/wealth_correlations.pdf) ...  [Same for Australia](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1467-8462.12461) ... [More of same](https://academic.oup.com/restud/article/87/4/1683/5538993?guestAccessKey=3a44e7e0-31db-4d5f-9d80-1f04ba38bb5a) ... [articles citing these[(https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?cites=2648517121766560937&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en)

Comment: An interesting frame challenge from Post-Soviet countries: Basically everybody had the same order of magnitude of income in the Socialist 80-s (and not much by first world standards). Hence, almost everybody who is rich now, earned their capital from scratch.

Comment: This question could show much more research. I'm sure that there are tons of studies conducted about such a topic. For example the GINI coefficient comes to mind and there is so much more. Maybe the question could also specify a bit more what equal opportunities mean or if everyone is equally poor also counts. For example in Ethiopia most people are more equal than in the US but it's mostly because they almost all lack opportunities. Is this what the question wants to know?

Comment: "If not, which country is the most egalitarian in this sense?" Be aware of statistical effects when comparing units of different size. For example, Denmark, which might be a good candidate, is much smaller than the US, rather on the level of a single state of the US. Fluctuations are always bigger if the units get smaller.

Answer (score 8):

**Likely not**, [at least by social mobility index.](https://www.weforum.org/agenda/2020/01/these-are-the-10-countries-with-the-best-social-mobility/)

> If you were born into a poor family in Denmark, it would take at least two generations to reach the median income, or three in Sweden, Finland and Norway. In France it would take six generations, and nine in Brazil or South Africa.

The US is 27th while China is 45th and India is 76th. Russian Federation is placed 39th.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socioeconomic_mobility_in_the_United_States#cite_note-13 is a good reference, too.

Comment: I'm a little concerned with how that source stated the claim: "It would take a least two generations to reach median income". Without definitions to clarify what they mean, it's easily falsifiable; there are plenty of examples of that happening within one generation in the US. The dataset shows it's not -common enough-, and that other countries do it better, but the link as stated outright says it can't happen (clearly they must have meant something else).

Comment: This ranking can be found in many sources  on the web, Scandinavian countries are mostly on the top

Comment: The rankings are in line with what I'm seeing, but they don't describe their methodology. And thus the meaning of their numbers.

Answer (score -5):

> Since defining class is difficult...

Actually the definition of class is at the root of any answer, and Marx distinguished classes by their relationship to the means of production.

The general idea of the American Revolutionaries was to establish the rights of capitalists against the aristocracy.

In the European "old world", most land was held by a hereditary class of aristocrats whose ancestors had acquired that land in military conquest, or through the political patronage of someone with military strength who had conveyed a landholding. The possession of land in this fashion conveyed certain practical rights to use a portion of the labour power of serfs, who also occupied those lands in a hereditary fashion.

Capitalist merchants established their wealth through networks of economic trade, and later by controlling investment activities (often at first relating to the "improvement" of land) and the contingent employment of farm managers and labourers.

These capitalist activities not only made the capitalists often richer than the aristocrats, but also challenged the traditional and hereditary principles on which both aristocrats and serfs defined their rights and obligations.

However, because the aristocrats controlled the law and other state machinery, they controlled the land on which all things must sit, and because their individual positions were heritable and could not be bought, they could typically subordinate the capitalists by extracting rent and by opposing any capitalist activity which (by either its nature or scale) would patently undermine the workings of the social order in a way detrimental to aristocrats.

The gradual transition of the Old World from feudal to the capitalist mode of production, eventually produced ideas that aristocratic rule should be completely overturned and replaced with capitalist rule. And the American Revolution is basically a fruition of these ideas.

Although there may be other strands of thought mixed in, when the American talks of "equality" he means a status between men which is not complicated by a biologically heritable status (as defines the aristocracy), and by "liberty" he means the freedom to engage in capitalist activity and pursue the interests of the capitalist class.

The inheritance of wealth is not precluded under this scheme, because it was not their intention to equalise the starting point of each generation, their intention was to unleash the capitalist class (whether its members had inherited their wealth or made it in their own lifetimes), and to allow the capitalist rich to rule according to their wealth.

> It is debatable whether the USA historically matched these ideals with slavery being a standout counteraxmple.

The *United States* of America, as a state entity, actually has a fairly unambiguous de jure record on the issue. It has opposed slavery and fought an internal Civil War over the issue of abolition.

The Old World too has generally rejected slavery as a radicalising and destabilising practice since time immemorial.

Slavery largely arose in the somewhat ungoverned and uncivilised space when the New World was being populated and converted to agricultural use by those emanating from and trading with the Old World.

The capitalists are not opposed to slavery on principle. The American Revolutionaries inherited (rather than established or promoted) the widespread practice of slavery, but within a generation or so they had purged it. They did so because of the contradictions it posed to their anti-aristocracy project, and because of the political and military weakness it would ultimately engender.

**Conclusion**

America does not even suppose to be an "egalitarian" society, and never has. It opposes specific forms of inequality and class society which are *not* based on possession of wealth, nor based on demonstrable competence in capitalist activity.

To understand what its conception of equality and liberty means, one must refer to the (largely defunct) feudal relations to which it was opposed.

The only vestige that may be witnessed today is in the virulent hatred that liberals, who might otherwise be quite content with undemocratic rich-rule, reserve for monarchs. They may make much of the monarch's special legal status, their tax affairs, even their holdings of hereditary wealth.

But the underlying objection of liberals is that the monarch has these things due to a *biological* inheritance, that the status of monarch cannot be sold by the incumbent or purchased by someone richer, and that the monarch is not required to engage in any capitalist challenge or demonstrate capitalist superiority to justify their continued occupation of their role.

Because the monarch continues to have *a different relationship to the means of production* in this way, liberals instinctively perceive the continued threat to their model, and that a relatively economically powerful and very well-known and politically powerful (and often popular) figure exists in the land who is not essentially a capitalist.

Comment: The 100 years between the declaration of independence and the civil war are a bit more than "a generation or so" until purging slavery.

Comment: Re:old world rejecting Slavery. Slavery didn't end in Britain until around 1800, with the US revolution being decades earlier. Your claims on slavery aren't accurate https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_Britain#:~:text=Slavery%20in%20Britain%20existed%20before,in%20English%20law%20or%20custom.

Comment: Re: American Revolutionaries, the "Four score and 7" years between the US revolution and the end of slavery is more than a generation. While many of them felt strongly about ending revolution, in the end they compromised to create the USA. Some states allowed it, and some states did not. Check out the Three Fifths clause in the US constitution.

Comment: Also, re: capitalists and slavery, American politics had a large conservative land holder vs more liberal capitalist schism. The North was more capitalists, and thr South held that, and their liberalism against them. While slavery was the cause of the Civil War, the South took issue with other parts of Northern culture too.

Comment: There are a number of useful observations in this answer, first being that the organizing principle of the US political system is *freedom* rather than *equality*. In its modern conception, there is the principle of *equality of opportunity*, which does have a well developed body of thought behind it [ https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rawls/ ] though adoption of these ideas, which I think best crystalized in the Vietnam war & civil-rights era, was distinctly selective and curtailed by neoliberal principles which in some profound ways are at odds with substantive equality of opportunity.

Comment: I think the core of what you wrote here, the transition from feudal hereditary focused culture into a liberalized capatalist culture, is what a good answer needs. But your American/European history needs work.

Comment: @lidar, I was thinking American Revolution to American Civil War as being roughly 75 years. It's actually 86 years - 1775 to 1861. I perhaps should have said "within a lifetime or so", but the point anyway is that it didn't sustain for long as a legal status, and there was hostility to the practice of slavery long before the Civil War adjudicated on it.

Comment: @bharring, that's nonsense. Slavery hadn't been legal on the British mainland during the entire memory of the common law. You might be getting confused with the tolerance of it in the British colonies.

Comment: "However actual ("de facto") slavery continued in Britain with ten to fourteen thousand slaves in England and Wales, who were mostly domestic servants. When slaves were brought in from the colonies they had to sign waivers that made them indentured servants while in Britain. Most modern historians generally agree that slavery continued in Britain into the late 18th century, finally disappearing around 1800.[11]" - the wikipedia link above

Comment: @PeteW, the organising principle I've articulated is *freedom for capitalists*. It's crucial to understand that they mean freedom to engage in capitalist activity, not any other kind of freedom. So too with "equality of opportunity" - they mean equal legal rights to engage in capitalist activity, and no rights which are reserved to those with particular biological lineages. They don't mean equal access to wealth, or fairness of the conditions in which each generation begins.

Comment: @Steve - I roughly agree with where I think you're going. I think we're talking about the line between beliefs of liberals, maybe what we'd today call progressive-liberals, taken at their high water mark in the 1970s IMO - vs the neoliberals who were the systemic response, and have since the Reagan/Thatcher period become integral to mainstream US "liberal" view of how a political system ought to be. Equality of opportunity, AFAIK, refers not just to money-power, but also to social / political position - esp participating in government and civil society, and education as its prerequisite

Comment: @bharring, it's important to note that the distinction between serfdom and slavery is the dispossession of the slave and the right of the master to treat the slave as his own movable goods, and to trade ownership to another master. It is not defined by the oppressiveness of the working conditions (as the serf might suffer and occasionally rebel against), nor captivity in one place (as the serf is), nor by a general environment of poverty that may cajole the *proletarian* to move around seeking employment.

Comment: As almost always, Wikipedia has a lot of detail on the subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_opportunity . It does refer to both economic and political rewards/power.

Comment: @Steve The citation was in reference to slavery, not serfdom. They are, indeed, different categories, despite both typically being disempowered proletariats.

Comment: Re: "America does not even suppose to be an "egalitarian" society" - see https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/declaration-transcript - "all men are created equal, that they are endowed by their Creator with certain unalienable Rights, that among these are Life, Liberty and the pursuit of Happiness" - eqaulity was literally their casus belli. One could argue whether they believe it or achieve it, questioning that is necessary and proper in your answer, but they clearly "suppose"d it.

Comment: (I post so much because this could be an absolutely excellent answer, if it were cleaned up for accuracy)

Comment: @PeteW, I'm describing what liberal has always meant in essence. The liberal does not necessarily agree with equal political rights like voting, since there were property qualifications and plural votes tolerated (much as the liberal seeks to extend the scope of the market, where the rich can exert force in proportion to their wealth). The "1970s progressive-liberal" in the USA is not really a strand of intellectual thought, but simply a mass of true conservatives who want to solve minor problems whilst reproducing the essence of the status quo. (1/2)

Comment: For reasons that are partly but not wholly related to propaganda, those who actually call themselves "conservatives" are often in fact radical liberals and an assortment of other reactionary forces, who don't want to maintain the status quo at all (as the post-war liberal typically does), but want to either go back to a purer form of liberalism or to innovate it into perceived new forms (as for example you see with the owners of tech platforms who espouse various forms of lawlessness and deviance). (2/2)

Comment: @bharring, can you organise your thoughts first and then post them as a minimal number of comment blocks? Modern liberal propaganda about what their own views consist of (as might be found on Wikipedia), does not decisively resolve the question of what actually moves liberals and what its essence has been over centuries. It's possible to have political movements that lie about their own intentions and nature, like a Nazi saying "work makes you free" or "this is the way to the showers".

Comment: @Steve - as I understand it, "liberal" taken in its classic international meaning has always meant freedom for capital. "liberal" in post-civil-rights US language morphed into a synthesis with social democratic ideas (sort of a follow-up to the wave of progressivism at the time of FDR), which already by the late 40's had organized opposition which would later coalesce into "neoliberal" ideology, to roll it back. Reagan/Thatcher were the back swing, and Clinton/Blair "new synthesis" marked the end of the debate, where neoliberal (classic international meaning of "liberal") won both US parties

Comment: (2/2) Some of the then-progressive ideas, esp to do with race and gender, remained - fortunately! Anything to do with matters of wealth- or income-distribution as causes of social ills got (again) demoted to second-class status in much of the discussion which actually counts.

Comment: @PeteW, we're obviously working from broadly the same understanding, but on race and gender, the liberal has never promoted racial politics on principle, or had any prejudice about gender. They'd happily send everyone down the mines for a pittance - man, woman, white, black, adult and child. In fact in the Victorian era, they happily did!